# Zend 2 with zfctwig - view helpers

Tags: zend-framework2, twig

I'm new to zf2, and I haven't been using twig for quite a long time...My question is - how do I use view helpers in zf2 with zfctwig module?

I mean, for example in kohana framework writing a public method in the view helper class automatically allowed me to display the return value of this function as a view variable. The names of the view class and view .twig files had to match. But when I tried it here it didn't work (I placed view helpers in `src/modulename/view`). Can I do something like this, and should it work this way?

Also, how should the view helper class look like?

And finally, should I use `return new ViewModel()` in my controllers to pass variables into view files?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this question by adding the following code to your module.сonfig.php.

```
return array(   
    'view_helpers' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'langWidget' => function($sm){
                 return new \Application\View\Helper\LanguagesWidget($sm);
            }
        ),
    ),
);
```

and you can use it in your template

```
<div>{{ langWidget() }}</div>
```

and this is example of my view helper

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\Di\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Application\Util\Util;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

/**
 * Widget with lang change elements
 *
 * 
 */
class LanguagesWidget extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected 
            /** @var \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager */
            $serviceLocator;

    public function __construct($sm)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $sm->getServiceLocator();
        $this->viewManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('ViewManager'); 
    }

    public function __invoke() 
    {   
        $config = $this->serviceLocator->get('Config');
        $appLangs   = Util::getSafeArrayItemValue($config, 'languages', array());

        $widget = new ViewModel(array(
                'langs' => $appLangs
            )
        );
        $widget->setTemplate('widget/langs');

        return $this->viewManager->getRenderer()->render($widget);
    }
}
```